DllMain is not called after injection
I had a working code that interacted with JNI. When I injected the DLL, everything worked. I decided to improve my program and add a GUI using ImGui and MinHook. After that, DllMain stopped being called at all. Could the *.lib files in the project have had any effect on this? In the project configuration, I changed only the directories of the added libraries. For the record, I tried to debug using Visual Studio, but none of the breakpoints worked.
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
//#include "Core/Patching.h"

#include "Cheat.h"
#include "Java.h"

void MainThread(HMODULE module)
{
    createEnv();

    if (getEnv() != nullptr) {
        //Patching::ApplyPatches();

        while (true)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) break;

            //runModules();

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    
    printf("DETACHED!!!\n");
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(module, 0);
}

extern "C" bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE instance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    static FILE* p_file{ nullptr };
    static std::thread main_thread;

    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
    }

    return true;
}

#include "Java.h"

JNIEnv* env;

void createEnv() {
    if (env == nullptr) {
        JavaVM* p_jvm{ nullptr };
        jint result = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&p_jvm, 1, nullptr);

        JNIEnv* p_env{ nullptr }; // JNI interface pointer
        p_jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, nullptr);

        if (env == nullptr)
            printf("Creating JavaEnv failed\n");
    }

    printf("Successfully created JavaEnv\n");
}


The set of valid operations from inside DllMain is restricted, in particular you can't start threads. Just read the documentation, it will tell you what you can and can't do.

@UlrichEckhardt Thanks a lot for the help, but I'm not sure if this solves my problem. Maybe I misunderstood? DllMain stops being called precisely when using GLWF and MinHook (I did not find out what exactly). If I just comment out their use in the code, then CreateThread will work and DllMain will be called

I'm not sure either I understand you. Can you provide a [mcve] that doesn't work and contrast that to the one that does? Your code above is incomplete, contains dead code and e.g. the function pointer cast on the CreateThread argument are invalid. Not a solid base for understanding.

https://github.com/Kisus228/CristalixCheat
This is a cheat created for the Minecraft project "Cristalix". https://cristalix.gg/. There are two commits in the repository. The first one is a working version, and the second one is a non-working one with uncommented lines

I fixed the error. The fact is that the MinHook project generates two versions of .lib files. One of them is designed to be used as an addiction, and the other is not. I got them mixed up. After importing the necessary library, everything fell into place. The correct file has the prefix "lib", and the resulting name is "libMinHook.x64.lib"
